# Cancel window event if node event is also triggered

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, mouseevent, dom-events

I have a situation where I have to attach an `'onmouseup'` event to the window. Clicking up should run a function everywhere on the screen except for when clicked up over a node. There is another `'onmouseup'` event handler on that specific node, so currently I can either run both functions or just window one (by calling stopPropagation).

I need to cancel the event attached to the window and run the one on the node instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.onmouseup = (e) => console.log('window mouseup');

nestedMouseUp = (e) => {
  console.log('nestedMouseUp');
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
.a {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.b {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="a" >
  wrapper
  <div class="b" onmouseup="nestedMouseUp(event)">
  nested
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yessss, thanks. I just forgot to not stop propagation in the window event handler, so it never got to the div onmouseup handler